# Problem with \rput command with XeLaTex and PSTricks

Tags: xetex, pstricks

After Ghostscript updated to 9.50, labels with `\rput` appear at (0,0) with PSTricks.
I'm using Texlive 2019 (with all the latest updates)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setmathfont(Greek,Latin,Digits)[Uppercase=Regular, Lowercase=Regular, Arabic=Regular]{Calibri}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-.5, -.5)(4.5, 4.5)
        \pspolygon[showpoints=true](0, 0)(4, 0)(2, 4) \rput(0,-.3){$B$} \rput(4, -.3){$Γ$} \rput(2, 4.3){$A$}
        \psdots(2, 0)(.75, 1.5)(3.25, 1.5) \rput(2, -.3){$M$} \put(.5, 1.6){$K$} \rput(3.5, 1.6){$Λ$}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I have absolutely no problem  (nut I'm not sure it uses the system-wide ghostscript or the version from my distribution, which is older).

Comment: +1. I have the same problem.

Comment: It is a problem with the lates 9.50 version of GhostScript. I have to investigate ...

Comment: Akira Kakuto fixed the problem and will upload a modified version of `xdvipdfmx`

Comment: Nice. Waiting for the fix then...

Comment: xdvipdfmx for Windows is updated in the TeX Live.
On other platforms, users should wait for TL2020, or
should build themselves by using new sources in the TeX Live svn.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto so a TeX Live 2019 installation on windows will not have this problem?

Comment: @Petros C: I have confirmed that the latest TeX Live installation
on windows does not have this problem. The preinstalled
Ghostscript in TeX Live for windows is version 9.50.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Thank you. I also test on Windows and it does work. On my Linux machine Ghostscript is also version 9.50. Temporally i will use \renewcommand{\rput}{\put} to work.

Comment: Is there a way now for linux users to solve this problem ?

Comment: @jadou It's fixed in TeXLive 2020.

Comment: I face the same problem again, with TeXLive 2020 this time. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in Ubuntu 20.04 with Ghostscript v9.50. The problem went away by installing gs v9.25 from sources downloaded from [this link](http:////https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs925/ghostscript-9.25.tar.gz). There was no problem with installation.

However, I also kept gs v9.50 in /usr/bin/gs as /usr/bin/gs95.

Comment: The link is either broken or not working properly at the time of this comment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Texlive 2020.

The good link is :
https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/tag/gs925.

Problem was solved by downloading and extracting ghostscript-9.25-linux-x86_64.tgz hen

`sudo mv /usr/bin/gs /usr/bin/gs954`

`sudo mv gs-925-linux-x86_64 /usr/bin/gs`

Thanks to Chak !