# \psframe works but \rput doesn’t in pspicture

Tags: pstricks, coordinates, grids

This is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](5,5)
  \psframe[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,dimen=inner,framearc=0.5](3,1)(4,2)
  \rput(2,2){X}
  \rput(1,5){Y}
  \rput(3,4){Z}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with `xelatex` I get the following output:

[image: xelatex Output]

But when I compile it with `latex` → `dvips` → `ps2pdf` I get a correct rendering:

[image: latex output]

As you see, the `\psframe` correctly render the given coordonates, but `\rput` seems to ignore them completly. I can give it any coordonate, the “X” mark still at the bottom right.

I use TeXlive 2020.20210202-3

An this is my `xelatex` version:

```
% xelatex -v
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Copyright 2020 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 67.1; using 67.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.10.4; using 2.10.4
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 2.7.4; using 2.7.4
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
Compiled with poppler version 0.68.0
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.13.1; using 2.13.1
```

What to do to get the correct rendering using `xelatex`?

Comment: What TeX-Distribution do you have and which program do you used? It looks like that you are using an old `xelatex` or viewd the dvi output. What happens if you use `lualatex`?

Comment: With lualatex I get the following error: ```! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.5 ...width=2pt,dimen=inner,framearc=0.5](3,1)(4,2)

?
```

Comment: 2020 is an old system which doesn't know `luapstricks`.  Run the example with `xelatex`, which should work  or use the route `latex`->`dvips` -> `ps2pdf`

Comment: With this way, it works correctly. But it’s necessary to use `xelatex` because all the project is build with XeTeX capabilities.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633412/pstricks-rput-command-seems-not-to-work-in-xelatex. A solution is mentioned in comments: `xelatex --shell-escape -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg" yourfile.tex`.

Comment: Also related (as linked from the other question) is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516100/problem-with-rput-command-with-xelatex-and-pstricks?noredirect=1&lq=1, which is the same problem but there the answers suggest to downgrade Ghostscript. This may not be the best advice but if you are ok with using older versions then that may be an option as well.

Comment: @Marjin: it is not a duplicate!  @fauve:  There was a bug in `xdvipdfmx`  years ago. However, you should update your TeX distribution: Valilla TeXLive https://tug.org/texlive/debian.html

Comment: @Marijn also the user who suggest to download ghostscript doesn’t have other activities in SE, nor than another user who came to approve him. It seems to be a scam.

Comment: @fauve it is not a scam, it will work for sure - Ghostscript imposes more restrictions in later versions that trigger this issue, so going back to a version without these restrictions will resolve the issue. However, it is not ideal because then you also miss out on other improvements in the newer versions.

Comment: @user187802 it is not so many years ago, I can trigger the issue with `xdvipdfmx` v20210609, so just over one year old. Also it _is_ probably a duplicate because the OP of this current question also uses old versions. Of course updating would be the best solution but there are other workarounds available as well. Finally my name has first the `i` and then the `j`, if you switch them I don't get notified of the comment :)